# AFCI/GFCI breaker tripping when I wire it to a different circuit

Tags: electrical

The breaker is a TYPE QAF 2 AFCI/GFCI, 20 amp.

The breaker was originally installed in my house to serve one circuit, and it had been working.  I moved the wires to have it serve a different circuit. The breaker trips as soon as I reset it. The circuit is from the laundry room.

To test further, I disconnected this one and connected the dining room circuit and it tripped also.

Is this indicating a bad breaker?

Comment: Is it tripping over-current, GFCI or AFCI? Makes a big difference in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: It's a AFCI/GFCI

Comment: I know it is an AFCI/GFCI based on the model #. The question is: **What mode of tripping is happening, over-current, AFCI or GFCI?**

Comment: Can't reset trips right away.

Comment: There should be some indication of the **type** of breaker trip.

Comment: When you are changing a circuit so it is on the AFCI... *what are you doing with the circuit's NEUTRAL wire?*

Answer (score 1):

No, the facts presented do not suggest a bad breaker.

Since it was fine before you messed with it, it is overwhelmingly likely that either you wired it up wrong or there is an actual ground fault further downstream in the newly connected circuit.

Answer (score -1):

If you removed the old circuit and with the new circuit, the breaker still trips, then there is a good chance you need to replace that breaker with the same type.

They do go bad/wear out/get weak.

I imagine this is an older breaker that was in the panel and is correct/the right type for that panel.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The breaker trips as soon as I reset it. The circuit. Is from the laundry room, I disconnected this one and connected the dinning room circuit and it tripped also. There is an outlet in the laundry room but has to be plugged into an extension cord. Unless the dinning and the laundry are in the same circuit.

Comment: @Fcarrizale  Has any electrical work(replace switch or outlet or light) been done on the laundry room or dinning room before the breaker started tripping, or it just started one day?

Comment: it is a TYPE  QAF 2 AFCI/GFCI

Comment: I do some remodeling and I was replacing cabinets, when I asked about the extension cord plugged into the washer. So they asked  If could take a look. It only affects that outlet.

Comment: Checked outlet it's good.

Comment: @crip659 Yes, work was done - read the question. The breaker was not tripping, and then the OP connected different circuits to it. Odds are the OP hooked them up wrong and there is likely nothing wrong with the breaker itself.

Comment: @nobody  You need to read the original post before the edits and comments.  That's when this answer was posted. Usually the good people here leave a comment that edits have changed the question and to revise the answer.

Answer (score -1):

That's a great way to test the breakers as long as you switch out identical breakers. Replace it with a new one. Verify that it's the correct one for the wiring.

Comment: Hard disagree, the OP’s testing method is not “accurate” as evidenced by the fact that the breaker was not tripping before they messed with it. The fact that is tripping for two circuits that the OP has hooked up strongly suggests that they are hooking it up wrong or there is an actual fault further downstream. There is no evidence the breaker is bad.

Comment: @nobody  My answer was based on the original post by the OP, not after all the edits were done. Read the original question before attacking  answers and DVing.   Usually the good people here leave a comment that edits have changed the question and to revise the answer.